# How to compile and link google tests in C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 but with Gtest installed by NuGet Package Manager?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, nuget, googletest

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on Windows 7.
I want to install gtest and gmock for C++ in newer way than downloading headers and binaries or compiling by myself.

I found Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage Nugets Packages For Solution
I chosen Online, then typed gtest. From search results I've found Google Test, so I've installed its for my current project.
After the installation the code below compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest\gtest.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace ::testing;

int factorian(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*factorian(n - 1);
}

TEST(factorianTest, simpleTest)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1, factorian(0));
    ASSERT_EQ(1, factorian(1));
    ASSERT_EQ(2, factorian(2));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

but it doesn't link:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl
>   testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)" (?IsTrue@internal@testing@@YA_N_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   testing::internal::scoped_ptr,class std::allocator > >::reset(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > *)"
>   (?reset@?$scoped_ptr@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@internal@testing@@QAEXPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) c:\Users\Grzegorz\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\tmp\tmp\Source.obj   tmp

So I opened: Project Properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>Input
and I added:
gtest.lib
but unfortunately I see:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'gtest.lib'   c:\Users\Grzegorz\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\tmp\tmp\LINK    tmp

when I add full path to file (I know that I shouldn't) there are strange errors:

> Error 2   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)"
>   (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in
>   gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) c:\Users\Grzegorz\documents\visual studio
>
> > 2013\Projects\tmp\tmp\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)   tmp

so my question is **how to compile and link google tests in C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 but with Gtest installed by NuGet Package Manager?**

Comment: hey Grzegorz, I am having a similar problem, but the  Fix8 solution isnt working for me unfortunately. Can you have a look at my setup in this link, to see if you can see anything?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811621/visual-studio-unit-testing-errors-c-google-testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution:
when I typed gtest in nugets package manager in order to find the package I found multiple packages:

1. Google Test
2. FIX8 GTest Dependency Symbols
3. FIX8 GTest dependency

so I've installed also **FIX8 GTest dependency**. And the linking error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only answer I found that fixed my issue after tons of searching.

Comment: FIX8? What has FIX8 got to do with anything? I'm reluctant to install a package from an unrelated project.

Comment: Its not unrelated(maintained by google), also FIX8 usually means 64-bit prebuilt btw.

Answer (score 5):

Google Test NuGet package contains prebuilt library for static linkage only, but a default initializer for the packet's linkage options is "dynamic".

```
Project properties 
-> Configuration properties 
-> Referenced packages 
-> gtest 
-> Linkage: set to "Static"
```

And don't add gtest.lib manually.