# NuGet version of gtest not linking in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, googletest

After unsuccessfully trying the solutions suggested here:
[How to compile and link google tests in C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 but with Gtest installed by NuGet Package Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886725/how-to-compile-and-link-google-tests-in-c-project-in-visual-studio-2013-but-wi)

and only finding copies of these answers on other sites in desperation I am now representing this issue for consideration.

I have also been unsuccessful at trying to build either gtest or gmock in visual studio 2015 from downloads from github.

I confess that my patience is somewhat strained at this point.

EDIT:
Here is the dump on attempting to compile after implementing the changes suggested:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Bank_Account, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 19/03/2016 8:40:33 AM.
1>     1>
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>         Touching "Debug\Bank_Account.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>       ClCompile:
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>     1>
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(osfinfo.obj) : error LNK2005: __open_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __calloc_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __free_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __malloc_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(wsetloca.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(printf.obj) : error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>LIBCMTD.lib(vprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Facet_Register(class std::_Facet_base *)" (?_Facet_Register@std@@YAXPAV_Facet_base@1@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(bool)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@_N@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(cerr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(iosptrs.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xbad_alloc(void)" (?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Bank_Account.obj
1>     1>
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>     1>
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>     1>
1>C:\Users\Richard\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Bank_Account\Debug\Bank_Account.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.47
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please post details of your attempt to build gmock (downloaded from github) using VS2015. Building gmock 1.7.0 using solution provided in the package works for me without any issues (using VS2015).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/gtest/, you'll need to make just two changes to make that work in VS2015.

Firstly, change the `PlatformToolset` to "v120" (which is the VS2013 version with which the latest version of the gtest NuGet package was build):

[image]

Then, set the package linkage for gtest to "static":

[image]

That should make it work for you.

I've put together an example VS2015 project here: https://github.com/mthierba/SO36081425-gtest-nuget

If you'd want to use the latest VS2015 platform toolset (v140), you'll have to build gtest from source yourself or find another package that has a v140 version of it pre-built.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Unfortunately implementing your suggestions has not altered the outcome significantly. I just get a different, and longer, collection of linking errors. It seems to me that that there are more preconditions that need to be met in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do to successfully link **gtest** to your project:

1. Set platform toolset to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**, so that it matches the toolset used to build **gtest** NuGet package.
2. Go to **Project properties** -> **Configuration properties** -> **Referenced packages** -> **gtest** and set linkage to **Static**.
3. Finally, make sure you are linking your executable (that performs the tests) with the same runtime library that the **gtest** library is linking to. To do this, go to property pages of your test runner project and set **Project properties** -> **Configuration properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Code Generation** to **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)** (for Debug build configuration) or to **Multi-threaded (/MT)** (for Release build configuration).